# Node js - send response after all promises are resolved

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have a route defined in NodeJS Express.

The route calls a function multiple times (which returns a promise). Value returned from these Promises are added to an Array which is then send back to the client using res.json().

The problem that I am facing is that while Promises are getting resolved, res.json() executes as it does not wait for the Promises to return. I think some kind of chaining mechanism would be needed but can't make out how to do it.

Below is my code

```
app.get('/markers', function(req, res) {
       var markers = [];
    var marker1 = {"id": 1, "name": "London"};
 // Get the lat and lng based on the address
    geocoding(marker1.name).then(function(geocode) {
        marker1.lat = geocode[0].latitude;
        marker1.lng = geocode[0].longitude;
        markers.push(marker1);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })

    var marker2 = {"id": 2, "name": "Chicago" };
    geocoding(marker2.name).then(function(geocode) {
        marker2.lat = geocode[0].latitude;
        marker2.lng = geocode[0].longitude;
        markers.push(marker2);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
     var marker3 = {"id": 3, "name": "Munich" };
     geocoding(marker3.name).then(function(geocode) {
        marker3.lat = geocode[0].latitude;
        marker3.lng = geocode[0].longitude;
        markers.push(marker3);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
  // return the lat and lng array to the client
    res.json(markers);

})
```

How can I ensure that ' res.json(markers);' is executed after all the three Promises are resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which will resolve when all promises are resolved:

```
app.get('/markers', function(req, res) {
    var markers = [];
    var marker1 = {"id": 1, "name": "London"};

 // Get the lat and lng based on the address
    var prom1 = geocoding(marker1.name).then(function(geocode) {
        marker1.lat = geocode[0].latitude;
        marker1.lng = geocode[0].longitude;
        markers.push(marker1);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })

    var marker2 = {"id": 2, "name": "Chicago" };
    var prom2 = geocoding(marker2.name).then(function(geocode) {
        marker2.lat = geocode[0].latitude;
        marker2.lng = geocode[0].longitude;
        markers.push(marker2);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    var marker3 = {"id": 3, "name": "Munich" };
    var prom3 = geocoding(marker3.name).then(function(geocode) {
        marker3.lat = geocode[0].latitude;
        marker3.lng = geocode[0].longitude;
        markers.push(marker3);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
  // return the lat and lng array to the client

    Promise.all([prom1, prom2, prom3]).then(function() {res.json(markers);}).catch(function(err) {console.error(err);});
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could await for multiple promises results using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function.

You could also use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to prepare an array of promises to reduce code duplication.

And you should properly handle promises rejections.

```
app.get('/markers', function(req, res, next) {
  var markers = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'London'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Chicago'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Munich'
  }];
  // you could use .map to generate an array of promises
  var promises = markers.map(function (marker) {
    return geocoding(marker.name);
  })
  // and then use Promise.all to await their results
  Promise.all(promises).then(function (geocodes) {
    // you could use .map again to generate resulting json
      res.json(geocodes.map(function (geocode) {
      return {
        lat: geocode[0].latitude,
        lng: geocode[0].longitude
      }
    }));
  }).catch(next) // handle promise rejection
})
```